# Return value from nested Subroutine Perl

Tags: perl, nested, subroutine

We've received an assignment from school, where we're supposed to make our own small n' simple Perl application. I thought I'd make a ATM simulator. So far, it's been going great; I've created a menu (Withdraw, Balance, Transfer), by using subroutines. This is my code so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
#Written by: Tobias Svenblad, h15tobsv@du.se, Digitalbrott & e-Säkerhetsprogrammet (2015)
#PerlLab03-2c.plx

use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor;
use Text::Format;

my $firstname;
my $lastname;
my $acc_balance = 2451.26;
my $acc_withdraw;
my $clr_scr = join( "", ( "\033[2J", "\033[0;0H" ) );    #This variable will clear the screen and jump to postion 0, 0.

my $atm = Text::Format->new;
print color('green');
print $atm->center("ATM v. 1.20");
print color('reset');

#Create account message.
my $crt_acc_msg = <<"END_MSG";
\nDear Sir or Madam,\n
We're very happy you've chose us as your bank.
Before we proceed, we need to set-up your account.\n
END_MSG

print $crt_acc_msg;

&acc_create;
&acc_choose;

sub acc_create {
  ACC_BEGINNING:

    #First name:
    print "\nYour first name: ";
    $firstname = <STDIN>;
    chomp $firstname;

    #Last name:
    print "\nYour last name: ";
    $lastname = <STDIN>;
    chomp $lastname;
    if ( defined($firstname) && $firstname ne "" ) {
        if ( defined($lastname) && $lastname ne "" ) {
            goto ACC_PASS;
        }
    }
    else {
        print "You didn't fill in first or last name. Try again. \n";
        goto ACC_BEGINNING;
    }
  ACC_PASS:
    print "Please wait while the system loads.\n\n";

    #sleep(2);
    print $clr_scr;

    print color('green');
    print $atm->center("ATM v. 1.20");
    print color('reset');

    print "\nWelcome ", $firstname, " ", $lastname, "!\n\n";
}

sub acc_choose {

    sub acc_balance {
        print $clr_scr;

        print color('green');
        print $atm->center("ATM v. 1.20");
        print color('reset');

        print "\nYour balance is: ";
        print color('green');
        print $acc_balance;
        print color('reset');
        print " SEK\n\n";
        &acc_choose;
    }

    sub acc_withdraw {

      ENTER_AMOUNT:
        print $clr_scr;

        print color('green');
        print $atm->center("ATM v. 1.20");
        print color('reset');

        print "\nEnter how much you'd like to withdraw: \n";
        my $acc_balance_withdraw = <STDIN>;

        if ( $acc_balance_withdraw > $acc_balance ) {
            print "Insufficient funds.";
            goto ENTER_AMOUNT;
        }
        $acc_balance -= $acc_balance_withdraw;
        print "\nYour current balance is now: ";
        print color('green');
        print $acc_balance;
        print color('reset');
        print " SEK\n\n";
        &acc_choose;
    }

    sub acc_transfer {
      ENTER_AMOUNT:
        print $clr_scr;

        print color('green');
        print $atm->center("ATM v. 1.20");
        print color('reset');

        print "\nEnter how much you'd like to transfer: \n";
        my $acc_balance_withdraw = <STDIN>;

        if ( $acc_balance_withdraw > $acc_balance ) {
            print "Insufficient funds.";
            goto ENTER_AMOUNT;
        }

        print "\nYour current balance is now: ";
        print color('green');
        print $acc_balance - $acc_balance_withdraw;
        print color('reset');
        print " SEK\n\n";
        &acc_choose;
    }
  ACC_CHOOSE:
    print "[ ";
    print color('cyan');
    print "1";
    print color('reset');
    print " ]";
    print "Account Balance\n";
    print "[ ";
    print color('cyan');
    print "2";
    print color('reset');
    print " ]";
    print "Withdraw\n";
    print "[ ";
    print color('cyan');
    print "3";
    print color('reset');
    print " ]";
    print "Transfer\n";
    my $choice1 = <STDIN>;
    chomp $choice1;

    if ( $choice1 == 1 ) {
        &acc_balance;
    }
    elsif ( $choice1 == 2 ) {
        &acc_withdraw;
    }
    elsif ( $choice1 == 3 ) {
        &acc_transfer;
    }
    else {
        print "You entered an invalid option. Try again. \n";
        goto ACC_CHOOSE;
    }
    return ();
}
```

The problem I face is when I try to return the `$acc_balance` value to the other subroutines. I've tried to implement `return($acc_balance );` underneath the nested subroutines, but that'll just prompt me to end the application. So basically, what I'm trying to do is to update `$acc_balance` every time I make a withdrawal or transfer (they are both currently the same thing in this code), but whenever I try to do that, it either doesn't update the value or it'll just show the classic `"Press any key to continue..."` message.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide a *minimal* demonstration of the problem? There is far more code than required in this question. /// Please don't nest named subroutines in Perl. It doesn't help, and you can get into problems ("will not stay shared"). /// Please don't use `&foo;`. It's a very special form of calling subs. (The called sub uses the caller's `@_`.) While `&foo();` would be better, that is also special. (It instructs Perl to bypass the sub's prototype.) You should not be using `&` at all.

Comment: This makes me angry. Where are you learning to use an ampersand `&` to call subroutines? That hasn't been considered best practice since [Perl v5.8 arrived in July 2002](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html). Please ignore anyone who teaches you to do that — they know less about Perl than you do

Comment: @Borodin: Are you sure you mean my comments? I haven't added any here.

Comment: @choroba: You're right and I apologise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you shouldn't be using subroutines for this assignment. But it worries me that someone has told you to use an ampersand `&` when you call a subroutine and has explained how to use labels and `goto`. That's inappropriate for a modern computer language and you can do much better

For instance, here's how I would write your subroutine `acc_create`

```
sub acc_create {

    while () {

        print "\nYour first name: ";
        chomp (my $firstname = <STDIN>);

        print "\nYour last name: ";
        chomp (my $lastname = <STDIN>);

        last if $firstname and $lastname;

        print "You didn't fill in first or last name. Try again.\n";
    }

    print "Please wait while the system loads.\n\n";

    print
        $clr_scr,
        color('green'), $atm->center("ATM v. 1.20"), color('reset');

    print "\nWelcome $firstname $lastname!\n\n";
}
```

There's a lot more I could say, but Stack Overflow isn't the place for a tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Looks cute, but there are some things you shouldn't do. I'll try to show you with the *choose* part.

Don't call subroutines with `&`, but with parentheses, i.e. `acc_choose();` instead of `&acc_choose;`.

Don't nest functions/subs in perl. If you really want to encapsulate things (which I appreciate and recommend),
use modules. But that's beyond the scope of this question. You'll learn about that later.

Don't use `goto` if not absolutely neccessary. It makes the control flow weird, hard to follow, and often leads to surprises.

If you want to repeat something *until* a certain condition is met -- or, in other words -- *while* a certain condition is *not* met, 
use `while` loops.

Given that, I'd suggest something like this for the *choose* part (fancy printing omitted):

```
sub acc_balance {
    print "\nYour balance is: $acc_balance SEK\n\n";
}

sub acc_withdraw {
    my $acc_balance_withdraw = 0;

    do {
        print "\nEnter how much you'd like to withdraw: \n";
        $acc_balance_withdraw = <STDIN>;

        if ( $acc_balance_withdraw > $acc_balance ) {
            print "Insufficient funds.\n";
        }
    } while( $acc_balance_withdraw > $acc_balance );

    # if you get here, then $acc_balance_withdraw <= $acc_balance, so:      
    $acc_balance -= $acc_balance_withdraw;
    print "\nYour current balance is now: $acc_balance SEK\n\n";
}


# actually almost the same as acc_withdraw() only with
# other screen output and no `-=` operation 
sub acc_transfer {
    # left as an excercise
}


sub acc_choose {

    print "[1] Account Balance\n";
    print "[2] Withdraw\n";
    print "[3] Transfer\n";
    print "[4] Exit\n";

    do {
        my $choice1 = <STDIN>;
        chomp $choice1;

        if ( $choice1 == 1 ) {
            acc_balance();
        }
        elsif ( $choice1 == 2 ) {
            acc_withdraw();
        }
        elsif ( $choice1 == 3 ) {
            acc_transfer();
        }
        elsif ( $choice1 == 4 ) {
            print "Thank you. Good bye.\n"
        }
        else {
            print "You entered an invalid option. Try again. \n";
        }
    } while( $choice != 1 && $choice != 2 && $choice != 3 && $choice != 4 );
}
```

One issue with your attempt might be that you called `acc_choose()` recursively, i.e. you called it from within itself. Together with `goto` that can indeed have entertaining effects.

Good luck and keep on.

Oh, and to answer your question: It is now really simple to have the subroutines return something. It is not neccessary here because you use global variables for `$acc_balance` (don't do that either), but if you'd like to, you could let the subs return the new balance like so:

```
sub acc_withdraw {
    my $old_balance = shift; # that's the first argument given to this sub
    my $acc_balance_withdraw = 0;

    do {
        print "\nEnter how much you'd like to withdraw: \n";
        $acc_balance_withdraw = <STDIN>;

        if ( $acc_balance_withdraw > $old_balance ) {
            print "Insufficient funds.\n";
        }
    } while( $acc_balance_withdraw > $old_balance );

    # if you get here, then $acc_balance_withdraw <= $acc_balance, so:      
    my $new_balance = $old_balance - $acc_balance_withdraw;
    print "\nYour current balance is now: $new_balance SEK\n\n";
    return $new_balance;
}

# and then...

$acc_balance = acc_withdraw($acc_balance);
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the formatting and colouring, as it's irrelevant to the question. Here's how you can do it: everything a subroutine needs gets from its arguments, everything it changes is returned.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

sub create {
    print << 'END_MSG';

Dear Sir or Madam,

We're very happy you've chose us as your bank.
Before we proceed, we need to set-up your account.

END_MSG

    my ($firstname, $lastname);

    my $first = 1;
    while (! defined $firstname || ! defined $lastname
           || q() eq $firstname || q() eq $lastname
          ) {
        say "You didn't fill in first or last name. Try again." unless $first;
        undef $first;

        print "\nYour first name: ";
        chomp( $firstname = <STDIN> );

        print "\nYour last name: ";
        chomp( $lastname = <STDIN> );
    }

    say "Please wait while the system loads.\n";

    say "\nWelcome ", $firstname, " ", $lastname, "!\n";
    return ($firstname, $lastname)
}

sub choose {
    my $balance = 2451.26;
    my @menu = ( 'Account Balance',
                 'Withdraw',
                 'Transfer',
                 'Quit',
               );
    my $choice = q();

    until ('4' eq $choice) {
        for my $i (0 .. $#menu) {
            say '[ ', $i + 1, ' ] ', $menu[$i];
        }

        chomp( $choice = <STDIN> );

        my @actions = (\&balance,
                       \&withdraw,
                       \&transfer,
                       sub {}
                      );
        my $action = $actions[$choice - 1];

        if ($action) {
            my $value = $action->($balance);
            $balance = $value if defined $value;
        } else {
            say 'You entered an invalid option. Try again.';
        }
    }
}

sub balance {
    my $balance = shift;
    say "\nYour balance is: $balance SEK\n\n";
    return $balance
}

sub withdraw {
    my $balance = remove('withdraw', @_);
    return $balance
}

sub transfer {
    my $balance = remove('transfer', @_);
    return $balance
}

sub remove {
    my ($action, $balance) = @_;

    say "\nEnter how much you'd like to $action:\n";
    my $remove = <STDIN>;

    if ( $remove > $balance ) {
        print "Insufficient funds.";
    } else {
        $balance -= $remove;
    }
    balance($balance);
}

my ($firstname, $lastname) = create();
choose();
say "Good bye, $firstname $lastname!";
```

Nested subroutines are not nested the same way as in Pascal. In fact, you can't nest named subroutines in Perl.

As shown, only use `&` when you need a reference to a subroutine.

Don't use `goto`. Loops are easier to understand and manage.

Also, make sure you don't erase the screen immediately after printing an important message ("Insufficient funds").

Comment: That's a lot cleaner than my solution but I think it also is more puzzling to the OP as it introduces hashes to subroutines and even anonymous subs. It's a good answer, but not for the OP, I guess.

Comment: I think your `while` loop should use `&&` instead of `||` to build the expression with `defined $firstname ...`

Comment: @PerlDog: Is it OK to only have the first name set, but not last name?

Comment: That's a lot of code to allow someone's name to be `0`!